# How to evaluate expression in view

Tags: angularjs

In my following code i am creating an `HTML table` with `table headers as First, second, Third` and than `row for each student`.

Depending upon score, I need to put `X` in cell under relevant column header.
**Example**

```
If score 10 than put X under First
If score 9 than put X under second
If score 8 than put X under third
```

Can i re-write`<td>{{score.Position}}</td>` based on above requirement as following.

```
e.g. 

<td>{{score.Position}} == 10 ? X :'' </td>
<td>{{score.Position}} == 9 ? X :'' </td>
```

**Code:**

```
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>First</td>
                <td>Second</td>
                <td>Tbhird</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="student in Students">
                <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{score.Position}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this

```
<td>{{score.Position == 10 ? 'X' : ''}}</td>
```

Or this

```
<td><span data-ng-if="score.Position==10">X</span></td>
```